# Using FileEntryForm after upgrading from Liferay 5.2.3 to 6.0

Tags: liferay, upgrade, liferay-6

During an upgrade from Liferay portal 5.2.3 to 6.0.6, I discovered that the class `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.form.FileEntryForm` has been removed.

On the web there is no help and my use of this class was:

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    FileEntryForm fileEntryForm = (FileEntryForm)form;
    FormFile formFile = (FormFile) fileEntryForm.getMultipartRequestHandler().getFileElements().get("file");
}
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks to all

Comment: -1: Please consider editing your question. It does not make any sense, what does this "I noticed that in version 6 not **eseste** more ..." mean?

Answer (score 0):

Now, it seems you want to fetch a file from the `request`, so here is how it is done in 6.0 :

```
UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
File file = uploadRequest.getFile("file");
```

It would help if you can explore the source-code for Liferay 6.0.6, the code I have given is from `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.action.EditFileEntryAction#updateFileEntry()` method.

---

A lot has changed in Liferay 6.0.6 since Liferay 5.x, the whole approach to development has changed. Now everything is a plugin including the **Extension Plugin** (ext-plugin). There is **no** Extension environment starting from 6.0. So you have to do a lot of code changes for upgrading to 6.0.

And among the OOTB portlets the Document Library has changed drastically and also there are a lot more changes in Liferay 6.1.x for Document Library.

I hope this answers your question, if I have missed anything or you want to know something more I will be happy to edit my answer.